# QFrame sin mosaico y centrado

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, layout, pyqt

buenas tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

from functools import partial


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("1.ui",self)

        d = {self.Inicio: InicioWidget(), self.Ventas: VentasWidget()}

        for button, window in d.items():
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(window)
            button.clicked.connect(partial(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget, window))


class InicioWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InicioWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        frame.setStyleSheet("background-image:url(Logo1.png);")


        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

       #grid.addWidget(title,0,1)
        grid.addWidget(frame,0,0)

        self.setLayout(grid)

class VentasWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentasWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ventas\nVentana"))
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ventas\nVentana"))
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QGridLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Ventas\nVentana"))





if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="topframe">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame#topframe{
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.384, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 127), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 15))
}

QFrame#topframe &gt; QPushButton {
    border:0px;
    border-right:2px solid #00cc00;
}

QFrame#topframe &gt; QPushButton:hover {
    border-right:2px solid blue;
    background:qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 93), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 153));
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>2</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Inicio">
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true"/>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Inicio</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Ventas">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Ventas</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Registro">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Registro</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Consulta">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Consulta</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Mensajeria">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Mensajeria</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="Salir">
         <property name="text">
          <string>Salir</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <spacer name="spacer">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeType">
          <enum>QSizePolicy::Fixed</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
          <size>
           <width>316</width>
           <height>20</height>
          </size>
         </property>
        </spacer>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
      <property name="currentIndex">
       <number>-1</number>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Necesito que el frame que coloque se muestre en el centro de la pantalla con la imagen que coloque de background dentro de el:

pero obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Si entiendo lo que quieres, el problema no es el centrado del frame (de eso se ocupa el layout perfectamente), es que por defecto la imagen se repite en forma de baldosas para poder ocupar todo el tamaño del widget. ¿Tienes una imagen con un solo logo y quieres que aparezca como fondo sin que se repita?¿Si es así debe escalarse para ocupar todo el fondo o mantener su tamaño original en el centro? si tiene que escalarse cuando la ventana cambie su tamaño ¿debe mantener las proporciones originales de la imagen siempre o no?.

Comment: @FJSevilla, debe de mantener su tamaño original y mantenerse al centro de la pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que establecer mediante qss que no se repita la imagen y sea centrado con `background-repeat` y `background-position`, respectivamente.

```
class InicioWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(InicioWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("""background-image: url(Logo1.png); 
                                    background-repeat: None; 
                                    background-position: center""")
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.frame,0,0)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]